# ELB command line tools not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, ec2-api-tools

I have downloaded the elb packarge from the AWS site and set the required environment  variables but I am unable to use the commands.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error:

```
elb-describe-lbs --aws-credential-file /home/prateek/credential-file-path.template 
elb-describe-lbs:  Refused: Signature not yet current: 20131118T182313Z is still later     than
20131118T125753Z (20131118T125253Z + 5 min.) 
AWSRequestId:56c9101b-5050-11e3-9f02-ff424c27b77f
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your system time is off. Most api tools require your system time to be within 5 minutes of the current time. Its one of the elements used to verify the validity of the request.